# Query without condition in MongoDB + C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to use the `collection.FindAndModify` and give it a `IMongoQuery` which selects all the documents. But I can not find how to create a query without any conditions!

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I'm using MongoDB C# Driver v1.8.3.

Here's my code:

```
var query = ???;
var sortBy = SortBy.Ascending(new string[] { "last_update" });
var update = Update<Entity>.Set(e => e.last_update, DateTime.Now);
var fields = Fields.Include(new string[] { "counter", "_id" });
var m = collection.FindAndModify(query, sortBy, update, fields, false, false);
```

I wonder what should I write in place of `???` to select all the documents!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an empty `QueryDocument`:

```
var query = new QueryDocument();
```

But keep in mind that `FindAndModify` will only modify the *first* matching document.

Comment: Thanks, and the thing about `FindAndModify` I knew that and it is wanted.